Upper estimation for Multiplicative Conductor of Extension of $\Bbb Q_p$
Let $L/\Bbb Q_p$ be a finite extension of $p$-adics of degree $n$. Let $f$ be the minimal number such $1 +(p)^f:=U^f \subset \text{Norm}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^*)$. The ideal $(p)^f$ is also called
multiplicative conductor wrt $L/\Bbb Q_p$.
Question: How to obtain this "elementary" upper bound $f \le v_p(n) +2$? ($v_p(-)$ is of course the $p$-adic valuation)
The question is motivated by this answer.
Starting point: Can we say something interesting about norm the of $\pi_L$, the uniformizer of maximal prime ideal of $O_L$ in this setting? We can always choose (after multiply with an unit) the uniformizer $\pi_L$ such that $\pi_L^e =pu$ with $e \le n$ ramification degree and $O_L^*$. Next, can we even assure somehow that this $u$ lives in some $ U_L^s =1+\ \mathfrak{p}_L^s$?
So if $L/\Bbb Q_p$ unramified then $f=1$ as then we can choose $\pi_L$ to be $p$. What if the extension is non unramified? ( ...not sure if that's finally the right strategy)
#Update: Some ideas. As on $\Bbb Q_p$ the norm $\text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}$ acts by taking $n$-th powers, ie if $a \in \Bbb Q_p$ then $\text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(a)=a^n$, we can naively try with $1+p$.
This give s$\text{N}(1+p)= 1+np + a$ with "higher rest term" $a$ with $v_p(a) < v_p(np)= v_p(n) +1$. That looks promising up to two things. Firstly this suggests $U^{v_p(n) +1}= 1+ (p)^{v_p(n) +1}$ is pretty close to be contained in $\text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^{\times})$ if we can "get rid of the rest $a$" - equivalently to such that $1+ (p)^{v_p(n) +1} \in \text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^{\times})$, and secondly, in the linked answer above it claimed that we easily get the estimation $f  \le v_p(n) +2$, ie that $1+ (p)^{v_p(n) +2} \in \text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^{\times})$. Where the $2$ comes from?

You know that the norm map of a degree $n$ extension, when restricted to the ground field, is just the $n$-th power map. Now how does that one act on the filtration of the unit group?

@TorstenSchoeneberg: sorry, what I previously wrote & deleted now make not any sense as I noticed. But, are you asking about what the norm does with the filtrartions  $U^m = 1+\mathfrak{p}^m$ of the unit group of $O_L$ or of $\Bbb Z_p$?

Or is the point you want to emphasize is that the norm "preserves the level" in the sense that it maps the $m$-th member $U_L^m$ to $U_{\Bbb Z_p}^m$?

Good questions, I was just throwing out ideas. I think first seeing what the $n$-th power does on the higher units in $\mathbb Z_p$ would give a lead, but I admit it would not fully answer the question.

@TorstenSchoeneberg: so looking at the binomial expansion of $(1+a)^n, a \in (p)^m$ I not recognize some striking pattern. $n$ is a priori unrelated to $p$, so it seems not that taking norm / $n$-th powers pushes it in higher unit. Or do I oversee something?

@TorstenSchoeneberg: #Update: yesterday I was overcome by blindness, clearly we can say more about $\text{N}(1+p)= (1+p)^n$. Taking binomial expansion we get that $\text{N}(1+p)= 1+np + a$ with "rest term" $a$ with $v_p(a) < v_p(np)= v_p(n) +1$. That looks promising up to two things. Firstly This suggests $U^{v_p(n) +1}= 1+ (p)^{v_p(n) +1}$ is pretty close to be contained in $\text{N}_{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^{\times})$ if we can "get rid of the rest $a$" - equivalently to

such that $1+ (p)^{v_p(n) +1} \in \text{N}{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^{\times})$, and secondly above it claimed that we easily get the estimation $^f  \le v_p(n) +2$, ie that $1+ (p)^{v_p(n) +2} \in \text{N}{L/ \Bbb Q_p}(L^{\times})$. Where the $2$ comes from?
Do you maybe have some ideas how to resolve these issues?
